# How to wrap every 6 divs of the same class in another div using slice?

Tags: jquery

An example of the divs I use:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="thumb" id="ipsc-thumb" >
        <a href="#featured"><img src="images/thumbs/ipsc-bwthumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb" id="ipsc-thumb" >
        <a href="#featured"><img src="images/thumbs/ipsc-bwthumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb" id="ipsc-thumb" >
        <a href="#featured"><img src="images/thumbs/ipsc-bwthumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap every 6 of these items with `.thumb` class in a div

```
<div class="scrollable"></div>
```

I wrote this until now:

```
var divs = $("div.thumb");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=6) {
    divs.slice(i, i+6).wrapAll("<div class='scrollable'></div>");
}
```

It doesn't wrap them in any div, where is my mistake?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You currently only have 3 div's with the `thumb` class. How will it wrap the 6th (non-existent) div?

Comment: I have about 30 in my html code, it would've been too much to copy them all here.

Comment: @Alex, all your `<div>` elements have the same `id`. That's not valid HTML, and might be confusing your browser.

Comment: Do you get any errors ? what browser are you using ? it works for me (add an answer) ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ryg2/ Works for me.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 4. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Nope. Tested on FF 3.6.20 and works just fine. What version of jquery are you using? It should be at least 1.2 if you're using `wrapAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkm4D/1/)

We iterate over every `div`s with `thumb` class which a multiple of 6 and select all the elements that precede that div. These six elements get wrapped in a `div` with `.scrollable` class.

Starting from an HTML like this (Zen Coding):

```
#slider
  (.thumb > ...) * 13
```

You get this (again, Zen Coding convention):

```
#slider
  .scrollable
    (.thumb > ...) * 6
  .scrollable
    (.thumb > ...) * 6
  .thumb
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.thumb:nth-child(6n)').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prevAll('.thumb').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="scrollable" />');
});
```

Edit: if you need to wrap the remaining `div`s add this line of code at the end:

```
$('#slider > .thumb').wrapAll('<div class="scrollable" />');
```

[Fiddle with updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/wkm4D/2/)

Comment: Nice approach. But that does not wrap the remaining elements (also wrapped by the sample code in question).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap each div individually, use [`.wrap():`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
divs.wrap($('<div class="scrollable"></div>"));
```

[`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) is used to wrap an entire set of elements with a single element, while `.wrap()` acts on each element of a set individually.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/yHXrE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be possible with a while loop, the solution below is ugly, but I think it works  -

```
var counter = 6;
while (counter <= $("div").length+1) {
    var gtexp = '';
    if (counter > 6) gtexp = ":gt(" + (parseInt(counter) - 7) + ")"
    $("div:lt(" +  counter + ")" + gtexp).wrapAll("<div id='scrollable'></div>");
    counter = counter + 7;          
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Feqpg/2/

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me - im using Chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/khRTm/1/

Perhaps having the divs with the same ID attribute is the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var  tut=0;   
$("div.thumb").each(function () {
//if tut%6==0 u can wrap with
divs.wrap($('<div class="scrollable"></div>"));
//after that tut++;
    });
```